# dc.js 4.2.7 pieChart with legend having extra space

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I am using `dc.js` to create some charts and one of the pie charts with legend is having issue with the whitespace.

I have tried fixing it by adjusting the width attribute of the pie chart but it didn't work. It only happens with a pie chart with legend, other charts on the page are well placed. I want to `remove` extra space on the right for the first chart as shown in the image. I want to remove the space marked in red to be completely removed and all three charts have equal space all around.

[image]

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srireddy13/2w5etp3z/1/) if you want to see a demo. Here is my html and JavaScript code.

I am using `dc.js` version `v4.2.7` and `d3.js` version `v7.8.4`.

```js
const statusChart = new dc.PieChart('#status-chart');
const data = d3.csvParse(paymentsCsv);

statusChart
  .width(400)
  .height(180)
  .radius(80)
  .dimension(status)
  .group(statusGroup)
  .legend(dc.legend().x(10).y(40).gap(5))
  .label(d => {
    if (statusChart.hasFilter() && !statusChart.hasFilter(d.key)) {
      return `0%`;
    }
    let label = '';
    if (all.value()) {
      label += `${Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100)}%`;
    }
    return label;
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="status-chart">
      <strong>Status Counts</strong>
      <a class="reset" href="javascript:statusChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">reset</a>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="quarter-chart">
      <strong>Quarters</strong>
      <a class="reset" href="javascript:quarterChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">reset</a>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="day-of-week-chart">
      <strong>Day of Week</strong>
      <a class="reset" href="javascript:dayOfWeekChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">reset</a>

      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <div class="dc-data-count">
        <span class="filter-count"></span> selected out of <span class="total-count"></span> records | <a href="javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover dc-data-table">
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div id="payments-csv" style="display: none;">
  id,client,date,amount,status 10000,genesis,2022-03-03,35.7,payment settled 10001,optimum,2022-07-05,29.64,settlement success 10002,optimum,2022-11-22,28.06,payment success 10003,citizen,2023-02-01,13.7,settlement error 10004,genesis,2022-05-02,53.25,payment
  settled 10005,citizen,2022-12-20,43.87,payment declined 10006,citizen,2022-04-02,91.28,payment pending 10007,genesis,2022-11-22,74.57,settlement error 10008,optimum,2022-11-22,59.31,settlement error 10009,citizen,2023-02-01,29.28,settlement error
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/4.2.7/style/dc.min.css"></script>
```

Comment: I have edited my post with a better image that shows the problem. I want to remove the extra space on the right on the first chart (marked X). If you see rest of the charts are all well aligned with no additional spaces.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain better, I want that extra space to the right of first chart to be removed. Look at the other two charts, they don't have any extra space around. I want my first chart with legend to look similar. Hope this clears it?

Comment: dc.js doesn't reserve space for the legend automatically. I think you probably want to reduce the width of the chart and increase [the left margin](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/MarginMixin.html#margins__anchor).